# How to check password writeback connectivity status through Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Within a tenant that is synced via Azure AD Connect with an on-premises AD it is possible to enable password writeback if you met some requirements (have needed license, configured Azure AD Connect, enabled option in Azure).

Within the Azure Portal this state can be checked and be changed and it uses the following Azure API call:
https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/PasswordReset/CheckWritebackConnectivityStatus

Unfortunately this call can't be done by myself, cause I don't have a valid token for this endpoint. So exists there any similar call within Graph (v1.0 or beta) to check if writeback is enabled or is it possible to get a valid token for this endpoint?

Comment: The [closest one i remember is the following API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/passwordauthenticationmethod-resetpassword?tabs=http&view=graph-rest-beta) which is supported with Graph. Apart from that  i dont remember the functionality is exposed in Microsoft Graph.

Comment: That's the method I already use. And if not enabled it returns in the operation status "Failed - Unknown". But I would like to inform our users *before* we try to reset a users password, so the needed check.

Comment: hmm, i hear you. Sorry i don't think something available around this from Graph perspective. Being said that you can consider filing [Microsoft feature request/ Uservoice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform), so that they can consider that to be implemented in future.

Comment: Tried my luck: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/get-current-state-of-azure-password-writeback-to-on-premise-ad/idi-p/2371200

Comment: That's great and thanks for sharing @Oliver. It will help the community or any fellow users who're in need as well :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because currently simply no method is available in MS Graph, but hopefully it will be implemented some shiny day.

Comment: Exactly you're correct, thats the reason i suggested you this way. You may want to go ahead, update the answer with the above feature request, so it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently no method is available within MS Graph to retrieve this information. So at least [a feature request was made](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/get-current-state-of-azure-password-writeback-to-on-premise-ad/idi-p/2371200).